# How do I had a rep to data output in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains sales info for 2 years. 2018 & 2019. I'm trying to show the top sales rep and total for each year.

I have query:

```
  select extract(YEAR FROM ts.orderdate) AS YEAR, max(ts.total) as total
  from total_sales ts
  group by year;
```

this give me the top sales for each year but when I add rep.

I get all the reps:

```
select extract(YEAR FROM ts.orderdate) AS YEAR, max(ts.total) as total, ts.rep
from total_sales ts
group by year,rep;
```

How can I include the top rep along with the top sales?

Comment: What database are you using, please? And what version? This can be solved with [window functions](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/), but some databases do not have them.

Comment: And please show us your schema. It's unclear what ts.total is and whether `max(ts.total)` will give you the total for a year, or the largest single order. Do you want the sales rep with the largest *single* sale for the year? Or the sales rep with the largest total sales for the year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use window functions:

```
select ts.*
from (select ts.*,
             row_number() over (partition by extract(YEAR FROM ts.orderdate) order by ts.total desc) as seqnum
      from total_sales ts
     )
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  In the event of ties, this returns one arbitrary matching value.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

You can also approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
select ts.*
from total_sales ts
where ts.total = (select max(ts2.total)
                  from total_sales ts2
                  where extract(YEAR FROM t2.orderdate) = extract(YEAR FROM ts.orderdate)
                 );
```

This returns all duplicates if there are ties.